# how to add the ahven framework

Tags: ada, gnat

I just installed ahven, but if I compile a testprogram with Ahven.Framework,
I always get a compiler error:

```
file "ahven.ads" not found
```

My files for ahven are just here:

```
/opt/ada/include/ahven/ahven.ads
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/ahven/ahven.ads
```

how can I tell gnat where to search?

Edit:
I'm using gnatmake on Linux, without any project file.

Comment: What OS are you using? Which version of the OS, GNAT, Ahven? Are you using a GNAT Project (.gpr) file?

Answer (score 2):

There's an ahven.gpr file, which should take care of the dependencies. Find where that file was placed, and then either add a reference to it in your project's .gpr file, or if you're using the gps IDE, right-click on the project name, select Project/Dependencies, and then do "Add From File".

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** you are using *gnatmake* **and** a *unix/linux* based system, You need to add a path to your gnatmake command. To look up how to do this type `gnatmake` and look for the `-I` option in the help screen that follows. Im not sure which one of your dirs would be appropriate to include. That should be found in your ahven documentation.